# Select min value AND timestamp of that min value from mysql query

Tags: mysql, max, min

I am trying to query min value of column and its timestamp.

Table "cars":

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | epoch_time | cars  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |     5 |
|  2 |          2 |    10 |
|  3 |          3 |    15 |
|  4 |          4 |    10 |
|  5 |          5 |     3 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | epoch_time | cars  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  5 |          5 |     3 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Tried so far:

```
SELECT min(cars), epoch_time FROM cars;
```

It picks up min value fine, but epoch_time is incorrect.

I am expecting epoch_time to be corresponding to min(value) associated (by row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery which finds the minimum value:

```
SELECT id, epoch_time, cars
FROM cars
WHERE cars = (SELECT MIN(cars) FROM cars);
```

Or, if you are certain that there would only ever be a single record with the minimum `cars` value, then we can try using a `LIMIT` trick:

```
SELECT id, epoch_time, cars
FROM cars
ORDER BY cars
LIMIT 1;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can try using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cars) rn
    FROM cars
)

SELECT id, epoch_time, cars
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Edit:**

Any of the three above queries could made fast by adding an appropriate index.  An index which would generally work would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON cars (cars, id, epoch_time);
```

Comment: Option 1 is painfully slow...

Comment: Try the `LIMIT` option, if that would work for you.

Comment: Option 2 - `LIMIT` - is THE BOMB! Fantastic answer! Thanks

Comment: Actually, any of the above three options could be made fast, if we add the right index.  But maybe you don't even need to do that.

Comment: Could you explain or share a link about the index to speed things up? I am eager to learn more.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.  Try adding that index, and all three queries should execute much faster.